JavaScript comparing two dates input fields
I have two date fields the first one is store in MSSQL database known as leavingDate the second is a date picker in the form where user have to select a date.
I need to make sure the selectedDate is not greater than the leavingDate but nothing seems to work.
I have formatted both dates to string and comparing them as follows:
leavingDate = '2023/11/30
selectedDate = '2023/12/29 //This is wrong

if(selectedDate > leavingDate)
{
   //do something because the date selected is greater.

}

Some of the selected dates works some don't so how do I make sure that the JS always works when comparing two dates (one from database and one from input fields using moment.js)

You will need to work with the Date object.
Bellow is a code sample that works in online js editor when comparing dates.


const leavingDateString = "2023/11/30";
const selectedDate1String = "2023/12/29";
const selectedDate2String = "2023/11/10";

const leavingDate = new Date(leavingDateString);
const selectedDate1 = new Date(selectedDate1String);
const selectedDate2 = new Date(selectedDate2String);

if (selectedDate1 > leavingDate) {
  console.log("date is bigger");
} else {
  console.log("wont go here");
}

if (selectedDate2 < leavingDate) {
  console.log("date is smaller");
} else {
  console.log("wont go here");
}

if (leavingDate == leavingDate) {
  console.log("date is same");
} else {
  console.log("wont go here");
}



Have in mind that this may cause some issues when comparing dates from db, in my case the timezones switched dates.

What could I have done without you man! Thanks you save my life honestly it works like gold. I'm getting constant results now rather then working and not working as I was having before, any dates now I select works fine. I'm so grateful for the swift time you took to reply. Thanks for the knowledge shared.

No problem man :D
